# Chaining remove() to fadeOut() avoids animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just a simple question.

I have this chain:

```
$(this).fadeOut(800); //which works good.
```

Then tried to remove it:

```
$(this).fadeOut(800).remove(); //makes it remove instantly, without fadeOut effect.
```

Any help?

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#fadeOut-duration-complete

Comment: What is the question here? I'm confused...

Comment: This occurs because ```remove()``` executes before ```fadeOut(800)``` has completed. I wont post an answer as there's more than enough now; **but they've all neglected exactly why this happens.**

Comment: The answer was right there in the link you provided: "A function to call once the animation is complete."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to try using the complete callback function for `fadeOut`:

```
$(this).fadeOut(800, function(){
  $(this).remove(); //This will execute once the fadeOut is completed.
});
```

Probably cache `$(this)`:

```
 var $this = $(this);
   $this.fadeOut(800, function(){
      $this.remove(); //This will execute once the fadeOut is completed.
    });
```

Syntax:

> .fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )

*While invoking the `remove()` as a chain after the `fadeOut()` it will get invoked immediately after starting the animation and won't wait for the animation to complete; hence you want to utilize the complete callback to ensure this is done after the animation is complete.*

Just to extend the answer with another option using [promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) and `done()`

```
 var $this = $(this);
 $this.fadeOut(800).css('background-color', 'blue')
                    .promise()
                      .done(function () {
                         $this.remove();
                      });
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xsSEr/)

Comment: Oh, now I see he wanted to remove it on fadeout finish.

Comment: _"in case you want to do some activity right after animation starts and then remove on completion."_ - Why does the promise syntax help with that? Even with the "standard" callback syntax you could chain additional things before or after `fadeOut()` and they would take place straight away...

Answer (score 3):

Use the callback:

```
$(this).fadeOut(800, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The problem is that the `remove()` function doesn't wait for the animation to complete, and simply removes the element; whereas using the callback calls the `remove()` only after the animation is completed.

References:

- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 2):

Execute the `remove` method in the **callback** of `fadeOut` method

```
$(this).fadeOut(800,function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).fadeOut(800, function() { $(this).remove(); });` instead. By putting `.remove()` in a callback, it will only fire once the animation is complete.

Comment: **This is the only answer that actually provides *the OP with any inclination* as to what behaviour he is actually observing.** Come on guys, it's cool posting an answer to be the quickest - but it doesn't exactly mean a lot if the OP doesn't understand why it occurs.

Comment: @FergusMorrow I agree 100% and updated my answer with the reason. Somehow i forgot to mention that.. :) and +1 for Peacock... :)

Answer (score 1):

use fadeOut callback function

```
$(this).fadeOut(800,function(){
  $(this).remove();
})
```